# How to test all elements from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-3.7

I have a list of integers. I want to supply each integer to the test method.

Here is how my test method looks like:

`my_test.py`:

```
import pytest

def test_mt(some_number):
    assert(some_number == 4)
```

`conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def do_something(request):
    #Will be read from a file in real tests.
    #Path to the file is supplied via command line when running pytest
    list_int = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    #How to run test_mt test case for each element of the list_int
```

**In case I prepared some arguments to be tested how can I supply them to a test case defined by the** `test_mt` **function in my case?**

Comment: Do you want to apply the test_mt() function to each element of the list_int?

Comment: using for loop?

Comment: @ChayanBansal Exactly. Is there a way to do it in `pytest`?

Comment: as @HarshaBiyani said, u can use for loop or even use map function

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I want to run `python -m pytest --test-cases /path/to/the/file` so there will be as many test case runs as integers in the file

Comment: @ChayanBansal You mean run it by hand in the for loop? So what is pytest for?

Comment: @SomeName and what you want to assert?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani In this simplified case I want to assert that each number equals to 4

Comment: @SomeName: can't you modify `test_mt` by sending `some_number` as list?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Would like to avoid it. And test each number in a separate test case. Sending the whole list is simple anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `parametrize` instead of `fixture`

```
def do_something():
    #Will be read from a file in real tests.
    #Path to the file is supplied via command line when running pytest
    list_int = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    for i in list_int:
        yield i


@pytest.mark.parametrize('some_number', do_something())
def test_mt(some_number):
    assert(some_number == 4)
```

This will run the test 4 times, each time with different number in `some_number`.